# AngularJS Directive utilizando class

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directives

Preciso criar uma diretiva mas por questão de organização gostaria de fazer em uma classe, mas está dando um erro que não consigo identificar.
O que tenho é o seguinte:

Minha classe:

```
class MyDirective
  restrict: "E"
  replace: true
  scope:
    myVar: '='
  template: "<div>{{ myFunction(myVar) }}</div>"

  link: (scope, element, attrs, form)->
    scope.myFunction = (val)->
      //do something
      return 'my content'
```

Meu app:

```
myApp = angular.module('myApp', [ 'ngRoute', 'ngResource'])
myApp.directive "mydirective", MyDirective
```

encontro o seguinte erro:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'compile' of undefined

Inserido a função diretamente na diretiva funciona, estou fazendo algo errado ou realmente o angular não tem esse tipo de suporte?

Comment: Você pode postar a função gerada em JavaScript para `MyDirective`?

Comment: Obrigado, já achei a resposta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontrei a resposta, o método directive do angular espera uma função, realmente não posso fazer uma classe, mas se quero usar uma classe posso fazer assim:

```
class MyDirective
  constructor: ->
    return {
      restrict: "E"
      replace: true
      scope:
        myVar: '='
      template: "<div>{{ myFunction(myVar) }}</div>"
      link: (scope, element, attrs, form)->
        scope.myFunction = (val)->
          //do something
          return 'my content'
    }
```